# Fluid images in .mdx file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

there's some way to make fluid an image imported in a .mdx file?
I have a Gatsby site base on mdx file post, I install gatsby-remark-image-attributes and gatsby-remark-images.

```js
{
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
      options: {
        defaultLayouts: {
          posts: require.resolve("./src/templates/blog-post.js"),
          default: require.resolve("./src/components/layout.js"),
        },
        extensions: [`.mdx`, `.md`],
        gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              maxWidth: 966,
              withWebp: true,
            },
          },
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-image-attributes`,
            options: {
              styleAttributes: true,
              dataAttributes: false
            },
          },
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-highlight-code`,
          },
        ]
      },
```

The style seems to work, but the images I pass in my mdx files aren't fluid at all.

```
![IO thumbnail](img.jpg#lightbox=true;max-width=270px;margin-right=23px)
```

Anyone knows if it is possible to have fluid images in mdx file?

Answer (score 0):

What about adding something like:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
  options: {
    maxWidth: 800,
    wrapperStyle: fluidResult => `flex:${_.round(fluidResult.aspectRatio, 2)};`,
  },
}
```

*Credits: [`gatsby-remark-images` docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-remark-images/#dynamic-wrapperstyle-example)*

**Disclaimer**: `_` stands for [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/) dependency. As you can see in the [`package.json` (line 15)](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-remark-images/package.json#L15) it's a dependency of the `gatsby-remark-images`. I would not recommend installing a huge library as `lodash` is only for this utility since it will increase your bundle size. You can achieve the same result as `_.round` using some vanilla JavaScript approach but as testing purposes may be interesting to try `lodash` to know if with this approach you are able to create a fluid wrapper.

Comment: I'll try and let you know!

Comment: I run into `ReferenceError: _ is not defined` error don't know why. Hovering the _ element it seem it recognise where it came from, but it doesn't work

Comment: `_` stands for `lodash`. As you can see in the https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-remark-images/package.json#L15 it's a dependency.

Comment: Unfortunately  it doesn't work right now, I'll find a better way later in the evening.